# Unable to connect to HIVE java

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

I want to use `org.apache.hadoop.hive` to work with metastore.

The hive(1.1) and hadoop(version 2.6 ) was installed on a linux server. 
My computer has a windows OS. Here, I am trying to create Hive conf.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf;


    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args){

            HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
            hiveConf.setIntVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORETHRIFTCONNECTIONRETRIES, 3);
            hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, "thrift://server:port");

            HiveMetastore hiveMetaStoreConnector = new HiveMetastore(hiveConf);
            if(hiveMetaStoreConnector != null){
                System.out.print(hiveMetaStoreConnector.getAllPartitionInfo("tablename"));
            }
        }
    }
```

**But I encountered a problem in `HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();`**

> SEVERE: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
>           java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
>              at 
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:379)
>              at 
> org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:394)
>              at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.(Shell.java:387)
>              at 
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.findHadoopBinary(HiveConf.java:2065)
>              
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.(HiveConf.java:332)
>              
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.(HiveConf.java:95)
>              at Main.main(Main.java:11)
>              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>              
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>              
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>              
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>              at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>           
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>              
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.(HiveConf.java:95)
>              at Main.main(Main.java:11)
>              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>              
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>              
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>              
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>              at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class null
>             
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:86)
>              
> at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:62)
>              at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.(HiveConf.java:335)
>              ... 7 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>              at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>              at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
>              at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:83)
>              ... 9 more

Should I install the hadoop client on my windows(winutils.exe)? Or should I include more libraries?

Also, 
I need to set conf only `hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, "thrift://server:port")`?

Or is it something to do with setting the smth?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What is clear is that this error occurs while your program is trying to find the hadoop binary (**ConfVars.findHadoopBinary** from stacktrace), and, since you get an IOException, a particular file(winutils.exe) can not be found by your program. Most probably you need to install the hadoop client on your windows machine

Comment: Thank's. I will try it.

Comment: It certainly can't hurt to try winutils.exe https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils. Once you've downloaded it, set an environment variable for `HADOOP_HOME`, and add `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` to your `PATH` too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but your code would not run on the windows machine, because the windows machine is missing hadoop library. I think it is not possible to have a true setup on bare machine. You would need some kind of VMware software to get the window machine work as hive client.

If you are trying to connect to hive through a program, you should try using Hive API, which exposes [JDBC way](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC) to connect to hive.

> **JDBC**
>
> HiveServer2 has a JDBC driver. It supports both embedded and remote
>   access to HiveServer2. Remote HiveServer2 mode is recommended for
>   production use, as it is more secure and **doesn't require direct
>   HDFS/metastore access to be granted for users.**
>
> The HiveServer2 URL is a string with the following syntax:
>
> ```
> jdbc:hive2://<host1>:<port1>,<host2>:<port2>/dbName;initFile=<file>;sess_var_list?hive_conf_list#hive_var_list
> ```
>
> where
>
> `<host1>:<port1>,<host2>:<port2>` is a server instance or a comma
>   separated list of server instances to connect to (if dynamic service
>   discovery is enabled). If empty, the embedded server will be used.
>
> `dbName` is the name of the initial database.
>
> `<file>` is the path of init script file (Hive 2.2.0 and later). This
>   script file is written with SQL statements which will be executed
>   automatically after connection. This option can be empty.
>
> `sess_var_list` is a semicolon separated list of `key=value` pairs of
>   session variables (e.g., `user=foo;password=bar`).
>
> `hive_conf_list` is a semicolon separated list of `key=value` pairs of
>   Hive configuration variables for this session
>
> `hive_var_list` is a semicolon separated list of `key=value` pairs of
>   Hive variables for this session.

Comment: Oh! Really? I can't use HiveMetaStoreClient in windows OS without using VM!? The problem, that i had at the top was solved. I include more libraries, and now - have problem in HiveMetastore hiveMetaStoreConnector = new HiveMetastore(hiveConf);

Comment: I know about connect by jdbc:hive2. But i think, the best practices is using HiveMetaStoreClient.